# Change date style when using regional settings in datetime2

Tags: datetime2

I can't seem to change datetime2's settings when using the option `useregional` to display the date in the language given to `babel`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[useregional]{datetime2}
%
\DTMnewdatestyle{mydatestyle}{
  \renewcommand*{\DTMdisplaydate}[4]{##3 \DTMmonthname{##2}}
  \renewcommand*{\DTMDisplaydate}{\DTMdisplaydate}
}
\DTMsetdatestyle{mydatestyle}
% -------------------
\begin{document}
\today
\end{document}
```

I'd like the output to be `08 settembre`, with the leading zero in front of the 8 and without the year, but I'm still getting the default `8 settembre 2019`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the main issues in your code are the following:

1. You need to use option `calc` for `datetime2`.
2. Use option `useregional=text` for `datetime2`.
3. Move command `\DTMsetdatestyle{mydatestyle}` after `\begin{document}`.
4. Use command `\DTMtwodigits{##3}` to get the leading zero ...

Please see the following MWE

```
\documentclass[italian]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[%
  useregional=text, % <=================================================
  calc % <==============================================================
]{datetime2}

\DTMnewdatestyle{mydatestyle}{%
  \renewcommand*{\DTMdisplaydate}[4]{\DTMtwodigits{##3} \DTMmonthname{##2}} % <============ year month day dow
  \renewcommand*{\DTMDisplaydate}{\DTMdisplaydate}
}


\begin{document}

\DTMsetdatestyle{mydatestyle} % <=======================================
\today

\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image: resulting date]

Comment: wow, this is my third question in a row that you answer in the span of 12 hours! Thanks a lot

Comment: @noibe :-) You are welcome!